# can't change youtube movie quality on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, youtube

I tried to change youtube video quality in UIWebView with youtube playerapi javascript.

reference 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

code

`ytPlayer.cueVideoById(movie_list[currentVideo], 0, "small");
ytPlayer.playVideo();`

but youtube player does not chenge movie quality.

Can I change youtube movie quality in UIWebView?

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **Playback quality** section from [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

The below function only sets the suggested video quality for the current video.

```
player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

The function causes the video to reload at its current position in the new quality. If the playback quality does change, it will only change for the video being played. Calling this function does not guarantee that the playback quality will actually change. However, if the playback quality does change, the onPlaybackQualityChange event will fire, and your code should respond to the event rather than the fact that it called the setPlaybackQuality function.

The suggestedQuality parameter value can be **small, medium, large, hd720, hd1080, highres or default**. We recommend that you set the parameter value to default, which instructs YouTube to select the most appropriate playback quality, which will vary for different users, videos, systems and other playback conditions.

**Quality level small:** Player height is 240px, and player dimensions
   are at least 320px by 240px for 4:3 aspect ratio.

**Quality level medium**: Player height is 360px, and player dimensions
   are 640px by 360px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 480px by 360px (for 4:3
   aspect ratio).

**Quality level large:** Player height is 480px, and player dimensions
   are 853px by 480px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 640px by 480px (for 4:3
   aspect ratio).

**Quality level hd720:** Player height is 720px, and player dimensions
   are 1280px by 720px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 960px by 720px (for
   4:3 aspect ratio).

**Quality level hd1080:** Player height is 1080px, and player dimensions
   are 1920px by 1080px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) or 1440px by 1080px (for
   4:3 aspect ratio).

**Quality level highres:** Player height is greater than 1080px, which
   means that the player's aspect ratio is greater than 1920px by
   1080px.

**Quality level default:** YouTube selects the appropriate playback
   quality.

This setting effectively reverts the quality level to the default state and nullifies any previous efforts to set playback quality using the cueVideoById, loadVideoById or setPlaybackQuality functions.

For more details, [**check here.**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)